# Ubuntu 20.04 boots slowly after regular update; boot and efi partition appear on toolbar and Nautilus left menu; files load slowly into editor

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, nautilus

Apparently after todays system update, Ubuntu 20.04 boots slowly.

Other effects are that boot and efi partitions appear on system toolbar and Nautilus left menu.

Also files load slowly into editor.

Dual boot Windows partitions do not show in Nautilus under "Other Locations" any more. However, they can be booted explicitly, e.g. using "disk" tool.

After the regular update with the standard software updater the system was in a surprising state: While sudo apt-get update did not do anything, sudo apt-get upgrade did changes referring to grub and efi - which should not have happened immediately after a flawless update.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix the problem?

Comment: Did Windows do update, when you were in Windows. That often turns fast startup back on which then hides NTFS partitions. Not sure why you are getting ESP seen, normally hidden. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair